# Use of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth* files

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager

What's the use of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` files ? In some cases ifconfig lists the interface `eth0` but I don't find the corresponding `ifcfg-eth0` file whereas in other instances if I create the `ifcfg-eth1` file and restart the network like `service network restart` - this interface is not listed in `ifconfig` ??

Comment: first check in `ifconfig -a` then it will show all interfaces, then configure accordingly

Comment: What I am trying to understand here is that does ifconfig use these files ? Who else uses these ifcfg-eth* files ?

Comment: @Shrddha I have updated and explain  ans

Comment: for more info run `man ifconfig`

Answer (score 2):

In RHEL/CentOS based system,

all Interface/Ipaddress settings saved in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`
the same you can find `/etc/network/interfaces` in debain/ubunt based OS

`ifconfig` If no arguments are given, ifconfig displays the status of the currently active interfaces, you can list all interface by using `/sbin/ifconfig -a` command and configure it.

when you restart service then it will reload settings from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` and shows in ifconfig

if you are able to configure it , then just use ncurses tools using below command

```
neat-tui
```

Note:- if `neat-tui` not work then you need to install `system-config-network-tui` package.

or from GUI login `system-config-network`

## Make sure you add the following option in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`

```
ONBOOT=yes
```

If you don't, the interface will not activate.

You can also *up* the interface using

```
ifup eth1
```

Comment: After you've edited the file, then `# systemctl restart NetworkManger` to make it so. (RHEL/CentOS)

Comment: `neat-tui` is deprecated. Use `nmtui`, which is in the `NetworkManager-tui` package.